# Windows 8.1 install mbr/gpt

Tags: linux, windows-8

I am trying to install windows 8.1 onto a partition on my drive, I already have Linux installed on another partition.  When I try to install windows it says something along the lines of windows cannot install on mbr drive and needs to be gpt however I looked on Linux using gdisk and it confirms that the drive is already gpt.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows can boot off GPT drives only via UEFI, without CSM (ie. not in BIOS-compatibility mode). If you have a GPT drive and want to boot via CSM, you're out of luck.

You also have to boot the installation media using UEFI in order to install to a GPT drive. Otherwise, installer will refuse to continue (as the resulting installation would be useless anyway).

If you're already booting with UEFI (non-CSM), then your installation media may be borked. To create a proper one, you'll need a Windows 8.1 ISO file which you can [download from Microsoft for free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO). You can either burn that ISO to a DVD or create a bootable USB flash disk using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). Make sure to choose *Partition scheme: GPT* and *Target system: UEFI (non-CSM)*.

If you're booting Linux via CSM, then you'll either have to convert disk to MBR (the hard way) or configure Linux to boot via UEFI (the hard-but-less-risky way). It will most likely involve chrooting from a live media and installing a package that enables GRUB to boot from UEFI. It's possible (I did it on Ubuntu), but I don't recommend it unless you're familiar with basic Linux boot internals or want to spend a few days learning. And don't forget to make backups.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I had a dual boot with windows/ Linux however after about a week or two windows stopped working so I formatted the windows partition with gparted and am now trying to reinstall windows.  I don't think csm would be enabled as the pc came with windows 8.1 pre installed.

Comment: @JohnCollins Actually the default I've been noticing in many factory installed Windows PCs is Windows installed in UEFI mode as it should be but the UEFI settings are typical UEFI+CSM. Because of that many users boot installation media the wrong way.This answer teels you everything you need to know about Windows requirements. Now check whether or not your Linux is installed in UEFI or Legacy (CSM) mode and if installed in Legacy in a GPT drive you'd better convert it to UEFI.